# Removing useless space from TextView after breakline

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm expriencing problems with TextViews...

Its seems like depending on the size of the next word before it breaks to new line, on its own, the string has no '\n' in it, t leaves useless blank space that I don't want.

This is the problmetic Textview:

and other times it goes like I want it to:

What is causing this? help :)

Comment: This question isn't really clear. Can you explain the specific problem you are experiencing? Do you want to add break lines to your text?

Comment: Can you see the extra space before it goes down a.line in the first picture? That's my problem.

Comment: @RachelBernouli Use android:gravity="center" to center the text.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem with you ? Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is a text justification problem. In Android O, Android introduced the `android:justificationMode` attribute.

If you are targeting Android O+, adding `android:justificationMode="inter_word"` should justify the text so that this doesn't occur. If you are targeting older versions of Android, you might be able to use some libraries ([here](https://github.com/programingjd/justified)) to achieve this behavior.